# Deciding which machine learning algorithm to use

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, classification

I got this question on a test. I'm not clear what the right answer is because all three are classification algorithms:

You have a ride sharing service where people can select their rides online based on price and time. A driver can transport more than 1 person at a time. You have information on the last 4 million trips (basically who took which ride).

The goal is to predict which future rides will have more than 'X' number of passengers.

Which algorithm would you NOT use:

A) Logistic Regression
B) Naive Bayes
C) Support Vector Machine
D) None of these

Any ideas? I'm really interested in the thought process here.

Comment: Without additional information, it looks like any of these algorithms can be used here.

Comment: Is this all the information you have?

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts. 

This is all the information that is given in the question, but is is assumed that you are the company providing the online service, and would have access to any information that such a site would be expected to produce. 
That would basically mean location of pickup (city), dropoff (city), and user IDs (and each user's history on the site). There would also be information like maybe how many messages the users send, profile pictures, ratings, etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depend, but with respect to these information, the answer is D,
Because you face with regression problem(**more than 'X'**), and A,B,C can use for regression problems(although naive base regression is not very popular)

Comment: This probably is the right answer. I had been thinking about the problem as a classification problem where you create two categories. "Over X" or "Equal and Under X", but I see that it could be reformulated as a regression problem. 
I'm actually curious, what would the difference be between using a regression vs a classification algorithm be in this case?